# Collect stream to List error: Required List<Integer> but 'map' was inferred to Stream<R>

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this stream:

```
List<Integer> l = stepElements.stream()
            .map(p -> p.select(STEP_ID))
            .stream()
                    .map(Element::text)
                    .map(Integer::parseInt)
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
          //.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Integer>::new));
```

Please remove this question as I only get negative reviews

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: @JBNizet I did delete question because anyone close him.

Comment: What is `stepElements` type ?

Comment: Please give me more negative reviews!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flatten your `Stream<Stream<Integer>>` into a `Stream<Integer` first, before you're able to collect into a flat list:

```
List<Integer> l = stepElements.stream()
            .flatMap(p -> p.select(STEP_ID)
                           .stream()
                           .map(Element::text)
                           .map(Integer::parseInt))
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in line 2 the closing bracket is missing.

I have next stream:

```
List<Integer> l = stepElements.stream()
            .map(p -> p.select(STEP_ID))
            .stream()
                    .map(Element::text)
                    .map(Integer::parseInt)
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
          //.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Integer>::new));
```

Comment: This can't work, you already have a stream with the map operation, you can"t apply stream again

Comment: @azro so, I need to collect List from a stream, but I can't do it since I have the stream again?